# Using Page/Post Slug In Link / URL

Tags: pages, slug

Hope this is easy!

Need to figure out (if possible) how to input my page's SLUG into a web url as a placeholder.

For example: http://www.samplewebsite.com/search.ashx?t=current

I need to replace "current" with my page's SLUG making it dependent on the current page's SLUG

For Slugs.... test1, test2, test3, test4, test5
Output... http://www.samplewebsite.com/search.ashx?t=test1 - for each test1 "slug"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Umm .. are you sure you are using WordPress :)

A standard search url for Wordpress uses the URL parameter `?s`   or `/search/`

so you can have any URL's you like such as `example.com/?s=current`  or `example.com/search/current`

Others you can try are `/tag/current`  search for all posts with the Tags `current`

`/category/current`  will search for all posts with the Category `current`

Does that help?